# Windows Server 2008 R2 VMware with BSOD error 0xF4

Tags: windows, vmware, bsod, windows-server-2008-r2

I moved VM from one machine to another, now Im getting 0xF4 error. Below is the Dump. Can anyone help me what I can do to fix it? Thanks!

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.10586.567 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [F:\MEMORY.DMP]
Kernel Summary Dump File: Kernel address space is available, User address space may not be available.

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 7 Kernel Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: Server, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 7601.18247.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.130828-1532
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`01c50000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`01e936d0
Debug session time: Mon May  9 11:21:12.155 2016 (UTC - 3:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:00:40.764
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
.....
Loading User Symbols
PEB is paged out (Peb.Ldr = 000007ff`fffd3018).  Type ".hh dbgerr001" for details
Loading unloaded module list
.....
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck F4, {3, fffffa80320bc8d0, fffffa80320bcbb0, fffff80001fca7b0}

Probably caused by : ntkrnlmp.exe ( nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak+92 )

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

0: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION (f4)
A process or thread crucial to system operation has unexpectedly exited or been
terminated.
Several processes and threads are necessary for the operation of the
system; when they are terminated (for any reason), the system can no
longer function.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, Process
Arg2: fffffa80320bc8d0, Terminating object
Arg3: fffffa80320bcbb0, Process image file name
Arg4: fffff80001fca7b0, Explanatory message (ascii)

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 401

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  7601.18247.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.130828-1532

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  VMware, Inc.

VIRTUAL_MACHINE:  VMware

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  VMware Virtual Platform

SYSTEM_VERSION:  None

BIOS_VENDOR:  Phoenix Technologies LTD

BIOS_VERSION:  6.00

BIOS_DATE:  07/02/2015

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Intel Corporation

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  440BX Desktop Reference Platform

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  None

DUMP_TYPE:  1

BUGCHECK_P1: 3

BUGCHECK_P2: fffffa80320bc8d0

BUGCHECK_P3: fffffa80320bcbb0

BUGCHECK_P4: fffff80001fca7b0

PROCESS_NAME:  wininit.exe

CRITICAL_PROCESS:  wininit.exe

EXCEPTION_CODE: (Win32) 0x1f (31) - A device attached to the system is not functioning.

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x1f - A device attached to the system is not functioning.

CPU_COUNT: 4

CPU_MHZ: 9bb

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 2a

CPU_STEPPING: 7

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,2a,7,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 28'00000000 (cache) 28'00000000 (init)

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xF4

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  TP-BOX

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  05-09-2016 13:30:48.0453

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10586.567 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80002053ab2 to fffff80001cc5bc0

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`039729c8 fffff800`02053ab2 : 00000000`000000f4 00000000`00000003 fffffa80`320bc8d0 fffffa80`320bcbb0 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`039729d0 fffff800`01ffeabb : 00000000`00000001 fffffa80`320ceb50 fffffa80`320bc8d0 fffff880`03972ae0 : nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak+0x92
fffff880`03972a10 fffff800`01f7e674 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 fffffa80`320bc8d0 0000007f`00000000 : nt! ?? ::NNGAKEGL::`string'+0x17486
fffff880`03972a60 fffff800`01cc4e53 : 00000000`00000008 00000000`0000001f fffffa80`320ceb50 00000000`001a66b8 : nt!NtTerminateProcess+0xf4
fffff880`03972ae0 00000000`76d7157a : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
00000000`0023f668 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x76d7157a


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  e9460336222f4471d8ae88a3d24ad7df3aff8ef1

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  f3953beab94a21de5fe7073bd16f274a5833cdfc

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  f08ac56120cad14894587db086f77ce277bfae84

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak+92
fffff800`02053ab2 cc              int     3

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  5c8b48cc

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak+92

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  521ea035

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.1.7601.18247

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xF4_wininit.exe_BUGCHECK_CRITICAL_PROCESS_1f_nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak+92

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xF4_wininit.exe_BUGCHECK_CRITICAL_PROCESS_1f_nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak+92

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  X64_0xF4_wininit.exe_BUGCHECK_CRITICAL_PROCESS_1f_nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak+92

TARGET_TIME:  2016-05-09T14:21:12.000Z

OSBUILD:  7601

OSSERVICEPACK:  1000

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  272

PRODUCT_TYPE:  3

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 7

OSEDITION:  Windows 7 Server (Service Pack 1) TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2013-08-28 22:13:25

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  130828-1532

BUILDLAB_STR:  win7sp1_gdr

BUILDOSVER_STR:  6.1.7601.18247.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.130828-1532

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 1286

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0xf4_wininit.exe_bugcheck_critical_process_1f_nt!pspcatchcriticalbreak+92

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {01613ae5-c73b-73b1-784e-ff59503f89d8}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the W8R2 install disk, selected Repair System, Advanced Options, SFC Scan, after it rebooted and system was working just fine.